# How to make a validation of textbox in asp mvc and entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have some textbox which I want that they accept only **NUMBERS (Int).**

I tried to do that with javascript but i failed because they are in form of a class **EDITOR FOR.**

Example :

```
<div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
```

So, I found in some tuto that I have to use **Data Annotations**

I tried to do like that in the model :

```
[Range(1, 100,
         ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 1 and 100")]

        public int Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
```

But when I press the button submit, this error always appears :

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details
```

I made some research about it,,I found that i have to use try catch. But I don't know where and how to use it.

This is the code of the controller (function when submit) :

```
public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
            Gamme G = new Gamme();
            G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
            G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;
            G.Last_Posts = model.PostePrecedentSelected;
            G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
            G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
            G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);
            ListG.Add(G);
            db.Gammes.Add(G);
            db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

**UPDATE :**
This is the Code of javascript affect on the button that will open the view :

```
<input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" /></div> 




<div id="divGestion"><%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %></div>
       <% } %>   
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {





                $('#btnShowGestion').click(function () { $('#divGestion').slideToggle("slow") });



            });

</script>
<fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like your FlowViewModel uses a `string` for `Nbr_Passage`, otherwise I don't understand the `int.Parse`. An int should work just fine.

Second, I don't see any [`Html.ValidationMessageFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) calls to add validators to your fields and you don't mention any call to [`Html.ValidationSummary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to render a summary for the form as a whole. You probably want to add (one of) those.

Comment: Thx for your answer, about the string and int.Parse : it's another issue of loading values,,I have to do it in String.
And I will try with the validationsummary in the view and give you result

Comment: I put Html.ValidationMessageFor  and Html.ValidationSummary  in the view but no RESULT !!!

Comment: As Muhammed mentions, are you also including JQuery validation on your page? And are the Validation attributes on your ViewModel as well?

Comment: yes I did all that staff,,,but the problem now ,,,when i include the js validation files in the code,,,the view (partial view) will not open :((

Comment: Define 'Will not open'. You might want to run through this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: The validation works for all the views,,,but it's not worked for that partial view,,,maybe because its opening depends on JAVASCRIPT affect on a button,,,,please check my UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

first You need to add two .js files named jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js included already in the test project made for MVC 3.

Then you need to add Html.ValidationSummary on starting of form.
Then you can use Html.ValidationMessageFor for each control.

example of using Html.ValidationMessageFor

```
  <div class="editor-label">
      <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
          <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
  </div>
```

In Model specify Required attribute and define the error statements.

Hope that helps

Comment: yes I did all that staff,,,but the problem now ,,,when i include the js validation files in the code,,,the view (partial view) will not open :((